# How can shared variables be implemented in a python class using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The program has two main functions which are running `while True` loops. The `clickSpot` function waits till `signal_found` is `True` and then clicks `self.spot`, a location on the screen, then increments `self.actions_done` by 1. `self.spot` is changed by `getInputFromUser`, while also displaying `self.actions_done`, which is changed by `clickSpot`.

Here's an example of the code I'm running:

```
import multiprocessing

class Program():
    def __init__(self):
        self.spot = (0,0)
        self.do_action = False
        self.actions_done = 0
      
        second_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.clickSpot)
        getInputFromUser()


    def getInputFromUser(self):
        while True:        
            self.spot = ...input changed by user
            ...displays self.actions_done
            ...input from user that toggles self.exit
    

    def clickSpot(self):
        while True:
            signal_found = check_signal() ...returns True or False 
            if signal_found == True:
                click(self.spot)
                self.actions_done += 1
                signal_found = False
            
       
    def exit(self):
        ...closes GUI in getInputFromUser and stops clickSpot process
```

My current implementation involves multithreading. However, both threads slow down when the GUI is being interacted with. I have not managed to get this to work with multiprocessing .

The expected result is to have `getInputFromUser` and `clickSpot` run simultaneously and share `self.spot` and `self.actions_done`.

Comment: Generally, all IO is handled by one thread. Are you talking about IO related events happening in two separate threads? That sounds like a big no-no.

Comment: seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), which will never be solved using the way you want to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem seems like something you should be doing "correctly" using multithreading and [Event Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) and [conditon objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition)

```py
while True:
    signal_found = check_signal()
    if signal_found == True:
```

is a busy wait, which WILL make your app slower using threads or burn a hole through your CPU if you ported this to multiprocessing, it should be replaced with a `threading.condition`.

```py
condition_obj1 = threading.Condition()
condition_obj2 = threading.Condition()

def clickSpot(self):
    while True:
        condition_obj1.wait()  # .notify() instead of setting signal_found=True
        click(self.spot)
        self.actions_done += 1

def getInputFromUser(self):
    while True:
        condition_obj2.wait()  # notified inside a GUI event that listens on user input
        self.spot = ...input changed by user
        ...displays self.actions_done
        ...input from user that toggles self.exit
```

this doesn't answer the original question which is how to share a variable through multiprocessing.

well, there are [multiprocessing versions of condition and event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Condition) and there are [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) and [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) for sharing values between processes, which allow sharing values, but this is not what you currently need.